# create form dynamically and submit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a jQuery plugin I wrote below, in plugin.js. I want to be able to also submit the form via JSON/AJAX every time it's created.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.create = function() {
        var form = '<div id="form" class="container">';
        form += '<div>User Login</div>';
        form += '<form action="/create/one" method="post">';
        form += '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">';
        form += '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">';
        form += '<button type="submit">Login</button>';
        form += '</form>';
        form += '</div>';
        $('#form').submit(function(e)
        {

            var postData = form.find('form').serializeArray();
        if(postData.name === "someREGEXstring" || postData.email === "someREGEXstring") {
        console.log("empty inputs not cool");   
        }
    var formURL = $('form').attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$('#form').submit(); //SUBMIT FORM

        return this.append(form);
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

in HTML view

```
<div id="newForm"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newForm").create(); 
});
</script>
```

Is this the correct way to make this or should I:

1. Create a another namespace under the same file for the AJAX portion
2. Create another namespace under a different file the AJAX portion

Comment: Consider using a template (e.g. in a dummy `script type="template"` tag, or passing the form as an option string). Otherwise it is a *very* specific plugin.

Comment: Q: Why do you want to submit the form immediately with blank values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is purely about how to arrange the code, I would suggest you pull the form template out of the code completely and make your plugin more flexible.

- Option 1. Create the form as a template in the page and pass the
  template selector to plugin as an option
- Option 2: Pass the template to your plugin

### Here is an example of the first technique: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/c8bmw/7/

### Template in HTML:

```
<script id="template" type="template">
    <div id="form" class="container">
        <div>User Login</div>
        <form action="/create/one" method="post"/>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

### Create with:

```
$(document.body).create('#template');
```

### And plugin simplified to:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.create = function(template) {
        form = $($(template).text());
        form.submit(function(e) {
            // This is the actual form object now
            var $form = $(this).find('form');
            // Test contents of form here

            // If values are correct proceed with Ajax call
            var postData = $form.serializeArray();
            var formURL = $form.attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // Stop default action
        });
        return this.append(form);
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Now your plugin code will work with any form.

*Based on your comment I have removed the automatic submit of the form, as that made no sense*

Comment: Oh I don't want to submit a blank form. I want to wait for the user input, check their inputs before submitting. That is why I was wondering if I should write a different function, say $.fun.submitForm inside the same namespace for the AJAX/JSON portion?

Comment: Putting that check first, inside the `form.submit()(function(e)`, is fine. If the test fails just don't call the ajax. If the form is dynamic though, what rules do you want to apply to checking the values? In theory you will need to use validation attributes on them and some form of standard jQuery validation plugin. Answer updated a little.

Comment: I just edited your code for what you said. can you check to see if that is correct?

Comment: Ah... just edited my own code too... what is your link? Please modify the JSFiddle :)

Comment: I don't have a link. it's really a dummy link bc this is just test code and I am trying to understand structure of writing forms as plugins

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46827/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-guest)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.create = function() {
        var form = '<div id="form" class="container">';
        form += '<div>User Login</div>';
        form += '<form action="/create/one" method="post">';
        form += '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">';
        form += '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">';
        form += '<button type="submit">Login</button>';
        form += '</form>';
        form += '</div>';
        form = $(form);
        form.submit(function(e) {
            var postData = form.find('form').serializeArray();
            var formURL = form.find('form').attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        });
        form.submit(); //SUBMIT FORM

        return this.append(form);
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Here is a demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8bmw/).

What is fixed:

1. `form = $(form)` is used in order to create the DOM elements based on the `form` string.
2. Change the way `postData`, `formURL` are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="#newForm"></div>
```

should be

```
<div id="newForm"></div>
```

to load this form element

Comment: OK - is that the correct way to attach JSON/AJAX to a form plugin so that it can be reused/

Comment: He answered before the OP changed the question.

Comment: @Aashray: That is unfortunate. Best he delete it then.

Comment: OK yes I made this edit. sorry. My question are still there - the 2 listed below

Answer (score 0):

I have some chages, like:

- `$('#form').submit(function(e)` should be `$(form).submit(function(e)` as variable form contains all the HTML of form wrapped within DIV.
- in the submit of form, `$(this)` will refer to the form element itself.

**Here is the modified code:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.create = function () {
        var formContainer = $("<div />", {
            id : "form",
            class : "container"
        }).append("<div>User Login</div>");

        var form = $("<form />", {
            action: "/create/one",
            method : "post",
            submit : function(e){
                var actionUrl = $(this).attr("action");

                alert(actionUrl); // just to check if this is working or not

                $.ajax({
                    url : actionUrl,
                    type : "POST",
                    data : $(this).serializeArray(),
                    success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
                    error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        })
            .append('<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><button type="submit">Login</button>')
            .appendTo(formContainer);

        return this.append(formContainer);
    };
}(jQuery));

$("#test").create();
```

**HTML for testing:**

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

[<kbd>JS fiddle:</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/y99mt/2/) http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/y99mt/2/

I have created the HTML nodes via jquery instead of just HTML string. attaching events to nodes is easier than converting string to HTML first and then attaching event to them. Hope you like it.

Comment: I actually don't want to submit it right away. I'm new and trying to learn about writing plugins so I thought i'd test it out here... Where should I put the submit function? Should I create a different $.fn.submitLogin as a separate login function and call it from the HTML view?

Comment: I got it, that's why I have made a comment there. Well, I have a POC on jsfiddle. Check that out.

Comment: Have you actually submitted your Fiddle example? It does a real postback as the code is not connecting to the form.

Comment: OK thanks! so you just removed "form.submit(); " and this should work when user clicks on submit? so let me get this straight, the submit binds to the any element with [type=submit] right?

Comment: `submit` event can be attached to FORM element only. and a form can be submitted through a button or keyboard as well.

Comment: @guest: No, submit() must be bound to the correct element. This current JSFiddle does not bind the `submit()` event at all and needs correcting.

Comment: I have created the HTML nodes via jquery instead of just HTML string. attaching events to nodes is easier than converting string to HTML first and then attaching event to them. Hope you like it. **updated my code and the fiddle url**, please check